# Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability

For a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$, let $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Is it integral
$$P(X>0)=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any random variable with a continuous symmetric distribution this is true. $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ has  these properties.

[ $P(X=0)=0$ and $P(X>0)=P(X<0)$. Hence $P(X>0)=P(X<0)=\frac 1  2$].